# Single click on any tag while editing tags, effectively double-clicks, displaying tagged question list

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tagging, retagging

> Single clicking on any tag while editing tags, whether to add or remove a tag, performs the double action of executing the click (adding or removing the tag as requested) *and then going to the list of questions with that tag* (loading the page questions/tagged/tagname, as though a second click on the tag had been done).

This happened when editing the Tags box under several different questions.  It was repeatable (and unavoidable) when trying again within each question and across different questions.

Comment: (Firefox 18 Mac OS X)

Comment: You should probably explain more detailedly what all this means —I, for one, have no idea :-)

Comment: @zyx Do you mean to say, "Single clicking on any tag while editing tags, performs the action of selecting the tag (what can be expected for a double clicking action) and then displays list of tags" ?

Comment: @OrangeHarvester: yes.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing this in Firefox (Windows,) not in Chrome. Basically, you can't delete a tag when editing tags in Firefox, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @zyx Do you mind if I re-write the question? It really has nothing to do with double-clicking, and I'd rather not submit a separate question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews -- sure. To make sure it's really the same: for deletion, when I clicked on the "X" delete button in (tag-name x), the parentheses and the X disappeared, indicating that the tag deletion process had started, but then the tagged-questions list loaded, and the result was to not complete the deletion, so no end result in the editing.  But similar problems appeared when *adding* tags: clicking on one of the auto-complete options loaded the tagged-question page instead of adding the tag.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Have you cleared your cache?